# How to make script stop from invalid intput

Tags: python, input

Need to learn how to stop the script once its evaluated the input is wrong

heres my question on 14/19 "Test run" for the python guide in codeacademy it asks you to double check your code and try all invalid inputs, my code worked fine for any number the user could input however, inputing a word would give back an error. So i attempted to fix that, my problem is now it evaluates that my input is not a number and prints out my invalid input error "Thats not a number" yet it continues with the rest of the script till it gets to my other invalid input error "Thats not even in the ocean" even though its a word and not a number.
so basically it now tells me that "its not a number" and "its not in the ocean" but i want it to just stop at its not a number. heres my code

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

print ship_row
print ship_col

guess_row = raw_input("Guess Row:")
guess_col = raw_input("Guess Col:")

if guess_row.isdigit() == True and guess_col.isdigit() == True:
    guess_row = int(guess_row)
    guess_col = int(guess_col)
elif guess_row.isdigit() == False or guess_col == False:
    print "Thats not a number!"
```

# Want script to stop here if input is not a number.

```
if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print "Congratulations! You sank my battleship!"
elif guess_row >= 5 and guess_col >= 5:
    print_board(board) 
    print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
elif board[int(guess_row)][int(guess_col)] == "X":
    print "You guessed that one already."
else:
    print "You missed my battleship!"
    board[int(guess_row)][int(guess_col)] = "X"
    print_board(board)
```

i appreciate any feedback, criticism is what helps you learn, right? and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need to stop script, just ask for a number again:

```
guess_row = ""
guess_col = ""
while not (guess_row.isdigit() and guess_col.isdigit()):
    guess_row = raw_input("Guess Row:")
    guess_col = raw_input("Guess Col:")

    if guess_row.isdigit() and guess_col.isdigit():
        guess_row = int(guess_row)
        guess_col = int(guess_col)
    else:
       print "Thats not a number! Try again!"
```

See how I also edited your if-else statement. `guess_row.isdigit() == True` is equivalent to just `guess_row.isdigit()` because it returns a boolean value. Same with `== False`, it is equivalent to `not guess_row.isdigit()`. Also you don't need `elif` because if one of the statements or both of them are `False`, you'll get into `else` statement all the time anyway.

If you really want to just end the program, then:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Good point id rather have the user re-input a valid number, and thanks for that tips helps clean it up a bit and clarifying the if else statement as i didn't fully understand its use to that point. i guess my new question once it does evaluate that its not a number, i do i get it to ask for input again from the user and redo the same check. and if everything is good to just continue one with the script. sorry for the questions im just new to this whole programing thing and i really want to learn and get a grasp on it.

Comment: @JayDR1 Yes, this is exactly what this piece of code does. You can also add some exit opportunity "Enter N to exit the program" and then there'll be just another elif with sys.exit() in it.

Comment: Wow, sorry i didnt see the "while", the codeacademy course hadnt explained that yet so i didnt even realize it was there. thnx for the quick reply. guess i need to go learn how "while" works now, i see that it works when i try it out so thnx again.